# Hash Table - resizing crashes program

Tags: c++, algorithm, hashmap

I have a problem with resizing hash table. Whenever I set size to bigger number, program crashes. However, it does not crash when I set that value to smaller one. I think the hash function (calculating new values) might be a problem, but I can't exactly tell why. Well, I assume that it's something about indexes.
Inserting elements from "old" hash table to new one works fine, but I just can't resize it.
Here is the code of resize method:

```
void resize()
{
    if (current_size >= load * size)
    {
        int newsize = size * cap;
        Node** tmp = new Node * [newsize];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            tmp[i] = hashtable[i];
        }
        delete[] hashtable;
        hashtable = tmp;
        size = newsize; //crash

    }
}
```

and here is the Node class:

```
class Node
{
public:
string key;
V value;
Node* next;
Node* data;
Node(string key, V value)
{
    this->key = key;
    this->value = value;
    this->next = NULL;
}
Node() {};
};
```

and HashTable class:

```
class HashTable
{
    int size;
    int current_size;
    int cap;
    float load;
    Node **hashtable;
    HashTable()
    {
        this->size = 5;
        this->current_size = 0;
        this->cap = 2;
        this->load = 0.4;
        this->hashtable = new Node*[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            hashtable[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking about redoing addTo method for all elements in resize method, but I don't know if that is the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So what value do you expect hashtable[oldsize] to have when you leave the `resize()`?

Comment: Many elements in `tmp` are not being nulled, but hard to say if this is the true cause. Nothing in the `resize` function will cause a crash without outside help. Something elsewhere in the code inflicted a mortal wound and the program finally fell over and died in `resize`.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
void resize() {
    if (current_size >= load * size) {
        int newsize = size * cap;
        Node** tmp = new Node * [newsize];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            tmp[i] = hashtable[i];
        }
        for (int i = size; i < newsize; ++i) {
            tmp[i] = nullptr;
        }

        delete[] hashtable;
        hashtable = tmp;
        size = newsize; //crash

    }
}
```

Would solve the immediate problem, but there is another error I suspect.

You will need to do a rehash of all your elements instead of the code in resize.

Comment: How would you do a rehash of all already insterted elements?

Comment: Edit: That works, thank you. I just need to rehash all elements right now.